# Is it possible to style two column layout for user input (so it overflows into the second column)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, user-input

I am creating a site that will be edited by a user later via CMS (Joomla!).

I'm wondering if there is a way to style (css) it so that when a user types text it automatically flows it into a second column when it reaches a set height.

So a two column layout...just text... when the text reaches say a height of 300px, I want it to go into a second column to the right of it at the top.

I'm curious if there's a way to achieve this using just css, it would definitely save me some time in javascripting.

Thanks again friends of Stack!

Comment: Not in IE7 with only CSS.

Comment: Ah, I thought so.  Well thanks anyway!

Comment: It would indeed be impossible with pure css in IE7, but the css3 columns are worth checking out. http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/ Thay would not appear in IE7, but I would consider that gracefull degrading. Yet another reason why IE7 users should upgrade, or move to a descent browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the CSS3 [column-count property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/column-count). There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn) to get it to work in older browsers.

```
textarea {
   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Safari & Chrome */
      -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
       -ms-column-count: 3; /* Internet Explorer */
        -o-column-count: 3; /* Opera */
           column-count: 3; /* W3C */
    height: 300px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nPxSL/1/